# Count the number of records in a range, matching another range, and satisfying multiple criteria

Tags: excel

I need some help figuring out how to do this.

I have two sheets, Product and Cities. In the Product tab there’s a list of products, each of which have many columns with details of that product. I’m concerned with columns P and AT, which are the City Code and Star Rating respectively.

On the Cities tab there is a list of cities with many columns for details of that city. I’m concerned with column F and A. Column F is the City Code, and column A is the Region Code.

So to start, I want to count the number of Products in each Region, to that end I have this:

```
SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Product!P9:P10000, Cities!F9:F10000, Cities!F9:F10000, D7))
```

Where D7 is the Region Code. The result of this seems to line up with my expectations… but are there any issues here?

The next step is counting Products in each Region where a Star Rating exists. So I just added a condition to ignore records with blank cells in the Star Rating column:

```
SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Product!P9:P10000, Cities!F9:F10000, Cities!F9:F10000, D7, Product!AT9:AT10000, “<>”&””))
```

This does not give me the result I expect (returning zero when I know there are records satisfying the conditions I wish to list).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Created a rough snippet of dummy data here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l7mIN1ilhYFJrFiKMR4HAHjraXB0x5ucQTjhIZZ-EQ8/edit#gid=0

I think I can see how this might not work, but I can't figure out how to make it work...

Comment: You can try replacing ("<>"&"") with ("*"). I've had issues where one works and the other doesn't for some reason. Worth a shot!

Comment: Why do you wrap a Sumproduct around a Countifs? And the Countifs looks strange too. You are passing a range into the criteria parameter?

Comment: Ok changing the "<>"&"" to a "*" hasn't worked unfortunately, thanks for your comment anyway.

This page explains why I'm using a combination of SUMPRODUCT and COUNTIFS.


https://exceljet.net/formula/count-total-matches-in-two-ranges

Comment: Again, why the SumProduct? Post a sample file in a free file sharing service like Dropbox or Onedrive, share it and post the link.

Comment: Alrighty, well I'm no excel wiz, but the SUMPRODUCT is there because passing COUNTIFS ranges means it returns an array. 

Here's a rough example of what I'm working with and my expectation.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l7mIN1ilhYFJrFiKMR4HAHjraXB0x5ucQTjhIZZ-EQ8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

referring the google sheet link you shared of 'Stack Snippet'

try using below array formulae in B3

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($G$1:$G$25,IF($J$1:$J$7=A3,$K$1:$K$7,"")))}
```

and in C3

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($G$1:$G$25,IF($J$1:$J$7=A3,$K$1:$K$7,""),$H$1:$H$25,"<>"&""))}
```

Comment: Wow thanks that works perfectly! So you create an array of the region's city codes before checking for matches with the product's city codes (with that if function). Thanks so much!